# How to find the opposite of .Any()

Tags: c#, .net, linq

My brain is failing me on a query I need to set up.

I have a Cat object that has two (relevant) properties:

```
public virtual ICollection<Ribbon> Ribbons { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Trophy> Trophies { get; set; }
```

Both Ribbon and Trophy has an integer property named "UmbracoActivityId"
The ribbons and trophies aren't directly related to each other but they're both related to a cat and an UmbracoActivity.  Cats get a ribbon for each "step" they complete in an UmbracoActivity and a trophy for finishing all the steps.  They're very competitive cats :)

What I need to do is get a count of cats who have started the UmbracoActivity but haven't completed all the steps (have not received a trophy).

**In plain English:** find all distinct ribbons where the cat that has the ribbon DOES NOT have a trophy with the same UmbracoActivityId as the ribbon's UmbracoActivityId.

**What I've got in code:**

```
var ribbons = db.Ribbons
   .Where(ribbon => db.Cats.Find(ribbon.CatId)
       .Trophies.Any(trophy => trophy.UmbracoActivityId == ribbon.UmbracoActivityId));
```

I'm getting close but the .Any() statement is true if the ribbon DOES have a trophy with the same UmbracoActivityId.  I need the opposite.  It's temping to just switch "==" to "!=" but in this case a cat could have many trophies with a different UmbracoActivityId.

I need the reverse the statement somewhere to search for the opposite but I'm not sure where to do that :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`.Any(x == y)` -> `.All(x != y)`

If there is any match, the first one succeeds. Else it fails.

If there is any match, the second one fails. Else it succeeds.

Comment: +1 This is actually superior to the `!..Any` as it will [short-circuit evaluate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) the results; so if the first is a match, `All` will instantly return, while `Any` would still check every item. Well, at least, I hope LINQ behaves like this! ^^

Comment: @poke: Good point. Although, I'm not sure how any / all would work with something like Linq to SQL.

Comment: @Trevor Pilley `.Any` returns on the first match. `.All` returns on the first non-match. They are opposites

Comment: @TrevorPilley Yes, but if you negate the whole thing, i.e. all `x` equal `y`, then `!Any(x == y)` will check them all, while `All(x != y)` will instantly stop after the first check. But yeah, thinking about it, it depends a lot on what the usually expected case is.

Answer (score 5):

Just use negation - i.e. `Where(ribbon => !db...Any(...))` (note the added `!`).

**If any** trophies share the same UmbracoActivityId, then the cat will **not** be included.

```
var ribbons = db.Ribbons
   .Where(ribbon => !db.Cats.Find(ribbon.CatId)
       .Trophies.Any(trophy => trophy.UmbracoActivityId == ribbon.UmbracoActivityId));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ribbons = db.Ribbons
   .Where(ribbon => db.Cats.Find(ribbon.CatId)
       .Trophies.All(trophy => trophy.UmbracoActivityId != ribbon.UmbracoActivityId));
```

Several ways to do it I quess, but this returns true if none of the cats trophies equals the ribbon.UmbracoActivity.

You could also use .Exist and "==" instead I suppose.